# Lookup and replace a bulk with nomatch

Tags: r, match

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
df.uid <- c(100, 101, 102, 103, 104)
df.code <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "1000", "1001")
df <- data.frame(df.uid, df.code)
df
  df.uid df.code
1    100      AA
2    101      BB
3    102      CC
4    103    1000
5    104    1001
```

I have a lookup table that looks like this.

```
lookup.id <- c("1000", "1001")
lookup.code <- c("DD", "EE")
lookup <- data.frame(lookup.id, lookup.code)
lookup
  lookup.id lookup.code
1      1000          DD
2      1001          EE
```

I used the following code to replace the wrong code with the lookup table and I get an error.

```
df$df.code <- lookup$lookup.code[match(df$df.code, lookup$lookup.id, nomatch = 0)]
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df.code, value = 1:2) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 5
```

If I take out `nomatch = 0` it will replace the good data to `NA`.

```
df$df.code <- lookup$lookup.code[match(df$df.code, lookup$lookup.id)]
df
      df.uid df.code
1    100    <NA>
2    101    <NA>
3    102    <NA>
4    103      DD
5    104      EE
```

How do I make it so the good data stays as is?

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` package as a `recode` function which can help with this. Something like

```
df$df.code <- recode(df$df.code, !!!rlang::set_names(as.list(lookup.code), lookup.id))
```

Comment: Thank you! It works on my sample data set. However, I tried it on my actual data. it comes out ``Error: `.default` must be type integer, not character`` I don't know what's different from my actual data than my real data..